# Tag removal request: [development]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-block-request

The [development](/questions/tagged/development) tag is on 1524 questions on Stack Overflow, and seems to serve no purpose whatsoever; it could very well be slapped on nearly every question on SO. Should this tag be nuked?

Comment: I cleaned up a few questions that would have been tagless once `[development]` is removed.  I guess mass tag removal is now a dev-only operation, since I get an error when I try it.

Comment: @Bill: just curious, how did you find questions with a single tag?

Comment: @Chichiray: The hard way, by scrolling through the list.  A SEDE query would have been nice, but it wouldn't pick up new questions with just one tag.  A search option would be better.

Comment: @Bill: You just scrolled through 1524 questions? Respect!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: The Wrath of Atwood