# Tag delete requests - [enabled] and [development]

Tags: support, tags, tag-block-request

The [enabled](/questions/tagged/enabled) tag and the [development](/questions/tagged/development) tag are both on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929587/coding-a-website-javascript-disabled). Neither one of these tags are informative and should be burninated.

I see that [development was taken care of once before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94327/tag-removal-request-development). It appears to have risen from the ashes.